# Impossible to change Windows XP Embedded ip configuration

Tags: ip, windows-xp-embedded

I have Windows XP embedded, used as video surveillance server.

I am unable to change its IP settings. Each time I change it and reboot I find the old settings.

I thought: "ok, it must be related to the video surveillance software" and decided to put in startup folder a batch file with `netsh` command to change the ip at every reboot.

With my surprise when I reboot this Windows XP embedded I find the *exact* operating system I tried to modify.
Same old ip, my batch file deleted.

It's like - just to get the idea - that the system gets a complete restore at every boot.
Maybe it's just the normal way XP embedded works.

Can I find any way to change its IP?

Comment: Well there is no "normal" embedded XP, each one is specifically designed for the device it is being embedded in. However I can tell you that the embedded machines I support do not perform this behavior. More than likely the OS is stored on Read Only Memory and when it reboots it doesn't write the changes to the flash device... just a guess it could also be a re imaging software on the device however that doesn't make much sense since part of the point of xp embedded is to fit on devices traditional xp won't fit on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Windows XP Embedded on a device before (Digital Signage device) and it writes a changes to protected memory, which is why your batch file and IP config settings are being deleted. You will need to enter the device's BIOS and *disable* this protection, make any nessecary changes, then re-enable the protection. This caught me out and caused me hours of confusion until I realised that this was the problem.

This is called an EWF (Enhanced Write Filter). The MSDN documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912906%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx), and a comparison between normal XP and embedded XP can be found [here (.pdf)](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBwQFjAB&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/1/2/71252520-2bb9-43c3-891b-bc09bfdde152/DifferencesBetweenWindowsXPEmbeddedandWindowsXPProfessional.pdf&ei=NmaLTfrCGMiyhAeZ-vm-Dg&usg=AFQjCNHCixnwp1J16vX36ffGOg6tJLEInw). Additiondal MSDN resources can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838511%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx).